# Postgresql schema "public" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

When I was working on postgresql database, I delete some users using command

```
=>set role "test-admin" ;
SET
=> drop owned by "test-admin" cascade;
DROP OWNED.   
=> drop user "test-temp";
DROP ROLE
```

but when I do

```
\dn
List of schemas
 Name | Owner
------+-------
(0 rows)
```

The `public` schema does not exist anymore. I can still see a bunch of users when run `\du`, I can also see names of database when do `\l`.

The error I saw is: "Error: could not find schema 'public' while looking for owner".

Looks like public schema was either dropped or not accessible. I did not drop schema explicitly.

My questions are:

- why does public schema disappear?
- will drop owner of schema public also drop public schema?
- how can I bring it back?
- Should I manually recreate it?
- Since I can still see databases, how can I associate the database with public schema again?

I tried all the approaches I can think of (such as login as users with different privileges), the public schema is still no available.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Where exactly did you get the "*Error: could not find schema 'public' while looking for owner*"?

Comment: Maybe you had changed the owner of the `public` schema to be `test-admin`? Then a `DROP OWNED` would have dropped it as well. Or somehow it was made to depend on `test-admin`s objects and the drop cascaded to it… We can't really tell unless you provide a full reproduction.

Comment: "*Should I manually recreate it?*" - yes, you can just create a schema with the name `public`. Afaik there's nothing special about it.

Comment: @begi. Thanks for the quick response I run `terraform apply`. Sorry I forgot the mention that.

Comment: @begi,  If I create public schema again, how should I associate the database with it?  Will the relation be like what created by default?

Comment: I update my description a bit. specifically, will drop owner of schema cause dropping public schema as well?

Comment: A schema is part of a (exactly one) database. You just create it while being connected to that database.

Comment: Did you drop the `public` schemas in multiple databases? Then you'll have to recreate multiple schemas.